# YII active record not inserting into database but no errors given

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've been losing my mind for this for a while now. I don't use Yii, I've just inherited some legacy code and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.
I'm adding a record into the database using active record.

The code is this:

```
    $result = new Result();
    $result->setIsNewRecord(true);
    $result->SourceId = Sources::CIP;
    $result->PartnerId = $partner->Id;
    $result->Result = '<h1>'.$partner->Name.'</h1>'.$raport;
    $result->ResultTypeId = empty($nasoale)?9:8;
    $result->Enabled = 1;
    $result->Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $result->CreationUserId = Yii::app()->params['sistemUser'];
    $result->LastUpdateUserId = Yii::app()->params['sistemUser'];
    $result->save();
```

This does not give an error. It even has an Id of the "inserted" query. Problem is, it's not in the database. Right after inserting this, I have another function that searches based on "PartnerId" and "SourceId" and it actually finds the record. I don't exactly know how, but it does.

I insert other stuff into the database the same way, in the same table and I did not have this problem before.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can `print_r($result->errors)` to see if there are any errors while saving

Comment: There aren't. I've already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you have multiple issues stemming from the same [core problem](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

### Insert, Missing In Database, No Error

This is most likely because a transaction was started, but a `ROLLBACK` occurred (or a `COMMIT` was not issued )

This can be somewhat confirmed, if the table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field and there are missing rows.
That is because you are not allowed to reuse AUTO_INCREMENT values, meaning if you rollback or do no commit, you "lose" the value...

[Read more here (specifically the first comment)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6714)

### Insert, Missing In Database, Next Query Finds The Data

This is most likely due to the way [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels) work.

If the secondary function **is running in the same thread** and is part of the same transaction, it will read the data.

If the secondary function **is *not* running in the same thread**, but the isolation level allows for dirty reads, it will read the data.

If you require more help, give a shout in the comments.

Comment: You were right. Somewhere in the code a rollback occurs. Still haven't found it but a quick, dirty fix with `Yii::app()->db->getCurrentTransaction()->commit();` after the save got the job done. Nice read. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome for the help and Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Check beforeSave for models. It must return true.

Comment: There is no beforeSave() method in my model. Looked for that as well.

Comment: What does $result->save() return?

Comment: it returns bool(true)

Answer (score 1):

Usually u will need to do some of this steps

```
if ($model->save()) { // do someting }
else { // do something other. u will find erros list here $model->errors;
```

or something like this

```
if ($model->validate()) { $model->save(false); }
else { // do something other }
```

Difference is because $model->save() by default do validation first and if it pass than save. But in some cases u will wish first to do validation and than if everything is ok do save, so u can pass false to save to escape validation.

In your case, since u dont have CDbException, its not issue with saving in database, it is usually issue with your model rules. So I suppose it will be best to check model attributes against your model rules, or even better your model rules against database and see if everything is ok. U can also do this by printing $model->errors on page if save() return false.

I hope this will help.